# Deleting Row from Gridview with SelectedIndexChanged

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have a gridview which has `SelectedIndexChanged` event implemented.  Now, I added a template field with a `LinkButton` to delete the row.  But, I'm not able to click the link button on `GridView` as it always fires `SelectedIndexChanged`.

How can I make Delete button work when `SelectedIndexChanged` functionality implemented.

```
     <asp:GridView ID="gvOnboardingMembers" runat="server" AllowPaging="True" PageSize="30" AllowSorting="True" OnPageIndexChanging="gvOnboardingMembers_PageIndexChanging" OnRowDataBound="gvOnboardingMembers_RowDataBound"  OnRowDeleting="gvOnboardingMembers_RowDeleting"
                        AutoGenerateColumns="False" OnSorting="gvOnboardingMembers_Sorting" EnableViewState="False" BackColor="White" BorderColor="#cccccc" BorderWidth="1px" CellPadding="2"
                        EmptyDataText="No onboarding member found" GridLines="None" OnSelectedIndexChanged="gvOnboardingMembers_SelectedIndexChanged" Width="100%">
                        <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="#ededed" />
                        <Columns>
                            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="OnboardingMemberID" Visible="false">
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:Label ID="lblOnboardingMemberID" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("OnboardingMemberID") %>' />
                                </ItemTemplate>
                            </asp:TemplateField>
                            <asp:BoundField DataField="FirstName" HeaderText="First Name" SortExpression="FirstName" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left" />
                            <asp:BoundField DataField="LastName" HeaderText="Last Name" SortExpression="LastName" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left"/>
                            <asp:BoundField DataField="Email" HeaderText="Email" SortExpression="Email" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left"/>
                            <asp:BoundField DataField="VendorName" HeaderText="Vendor" SortExpression="VendorName" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left"/>
                            <asp:BoundField DataField="BusinessFunctionDisplayName" HeaderText="Business Function" SortExpression="BusinessFunctionDisplayName" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left"/>
                            <asp:BoundField DataField="CreatedDate" HeaderText="Upload Timestamp" SortExpression="CreatedDate" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left"/>
                            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="">
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkRemoveEntry" runat="server" OnClick="lnkRemoveEntry_Click" Text="Delete" />
                                </ItemTemplate>
                            </asp:TemplateField>
<asp:CommandField ItemStyle-Width="20" ShowDeleteButton="True" />
                        </Columns>
                        <FooterStyle BackColor="#cccccc" ForeColor="Black" />
                        <HeaderStyle BackColor="#6699cc" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" BorderColor="#cccccc" BorderWidth="1px" />
                        <PagerStyle BackColor="#999999" ForeColor="Black" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                        <RowStyle BackColor="#fefefe" ForeColor="Black" />
                        <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#008A8C" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
                        <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#F1F1F1" />
                        <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#0000A9" />
                        <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#CAC9C9" />
                        <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#000065" />
                    </asp:GridView>
```

Backend code

```
protected void gvOnboardingMembers_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            e.Row.Attributes["onmouseover"] = "this.style.cursor='pointer';this.style.textDecoration='underline';";
            e.Row.Attributes["onmouseout"] = "this.style.textDecoration='none';";
            e.Row.Attributes["onclick"] = Page.ClientScript.GetPostBackClientHyperlink(gvOnboardingMembers, "Select$" + e.Row.RowIndex);
            e.Row.ToolTip = "Click to select this row.";

            DataRowView dataItem = (DataRowView)e.Row.DataItem;

            var removeEntry = e.Row.FindControl("lnkRemoveEntry") as LinkButton;
            removeEntry.CommandArgument = dataItem["OnboardingMemberID"].ToString();
        }
    }

protected void gvOnboardingMembers_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            foreach (GridViewRow row in gvOnboardingMembers.Rows)
            {
                if (row.RowIndex == gvOnboardingMembers.SelectedIndex)
                {
                    row.BackColor = ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#A1DCF2");
                    row.ToolTip = string.Empty;
                }
                else
                {
                    row.BackColor = ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#FFFFFF");
                    row.ToolTip = "Click to select this row.";
                }
            }
}

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            BindOnboardingMember();
        }

        private void BindOnboardingMember()
        {
            DataView dv = new DataView(DataManager.ToDataTable<OnboardingMember>(DraftMembers));
            dv.Sort = OnboardingMemberSortExpression;

            gvOnboardingMembers.DataSource = dv;
            gvOnboardingMembers.DataBind();
        }
protected void lnkRemoveEntry_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var lnkButton = (LinkButton)sender;

        }

protected void gvOnboardingMembers_RowDeleting(object sender, GridViewDeleteEventArgs e)
        {
            if(DeleteOnboardingMember(Guid.Parse(((Label)(gvOnboardingMembers.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[0].FindControl("lblOnboardingMemberID"))).Text)))
                BindOnboardingMember();
        }
```

On please let me know, if there is anyway to prevent PostBack on selectedIndexChanged.  I guess my delete events are not executing because my gridview is rebound every time page is posted back (see pageload event).  But, this is required in order to make SelectedIndexChanged work properly.

Comment: if you want to delete the rows, better use `onRowDeleting` for the row by checking the `ID` of each row.

Comment: I have implementation of RowDeleting as well.  It neither comes into RowDeleting nor Button Click.

Comment: how are you binding your gridview, it should be inside `IsPostBack` as Angus suggested.

Comment: I can't use IsPostBack as it prevents SelectedIndexChanged.  I'm in a loop! please refer my reply to that suggestion for the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I couldn't prevent this scenario but I implemented a work around using WebMethods on Delete click instead of regular RowDeleting event.

```
protected void gvOnboardingMembers_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            e.Row.Attributes["onmouseover"] = "this.style.cursor='pointer';this.style.textDecoration='underline';";
            e.Row.Attributes["onmouseout"] = "this.style.textDecoration='none';";
            e.Row.Attributes["onclick"] = Page.ClientScript.GetPostBackClientHyperlink(gvOnboardingMembers, "Select$" + e.Row.RowIndex);
            e.Row.ToolTip = "Click to select this row.";

            DataRowView dataItem = (DataRowView)e.Row.DataItem;

            if ((e.Row.RowState & DataControlRowState.Edit) == 0)
            {
                LinkButton deleteButton = (LinkButton)e.Row.Cells[7].Controls[0];
                if (deleteButton != null)
                    deleteButton.Attributes.Add("onclick", "return deleteOnboardingMember('" + dataItem["OnboardingMemberID"].ToString() + "');");
            }
        }
    }
[WebMethod(EnableSession=true)]
    public static void DeleteOnboardingMember(string onboardingMemberID)
    {
        if(new processingClass().DeleteOnboardingMember(Guid.Parse(onboardingMemberID)))
            HttpContext.Current.Session["DraftMembers"] = null;
    }
```

Script

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function deleteOnboardingMember(id) {
        if (confirm("Are you sure you want to remove this entry?"))
        {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "/OnboardingRequest.aspx/DeleteOnboardingMember",
                async: false,
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                data: "{ 'onboardingMemberID': '" + id + "'}",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function () {
                    window.location.reload();
                },
                error: function (xhr, status, error) {
                    var err = eval("(" + xhr.error + ")");
                    alert(err.Message);
                },
                failure: function () {
                    alert('failure');
                }
            });
        }

        return false;
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this way.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     if (!IsPostBack)
     {
         BindOnboardingMember();
     }
}
```

Comment: I tried that too.  It is required not to check IsPostBack as I have SelectedIndexChanged event.  If I validate that I will never get "gvOnboardingMembers.SelectedRow". It will always return an exception "Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection. Parameter name: index."

Comment: Could you put a download link with your project and db?

Comment: I can't do that as it is too huge. I tried to paste the actual code so far.  Please refer to my work around posted as an answer.

Comment: Please refer to my answer posted.  I have got it through a work-around. But it fulfills my requirement.

Comment: ok , i see it. It i s a good way to delete data by **WebMethod**.

Answer (score 0):

Given your Gridview definition (I've excluded cosmetic stuff):

```
<asp:GridView ID="gvOnboardingMembers" runat="server" 
    AllowPaging="True"
    PageSize="30" 
    AllowSorting="True"
    OnPageIndexChanging="gvOnboardingMembers_PageIndexChanging"
    OnRowDataBound="gvOnboardingMembers_RowDataBound" 
    OnRowDeleting="gvOnboardingMembers_RowDeleting"
    OnSorting="gvOnboardingMembers_Sorting" 
    EnableViewState="False" 
    EmptyDataText="No onboarding member found" 
    OnSelectedIndexChanged="gvOnboardingMembers_SelectedIndexChanged">
```

You have a basic misunderstanding on how events are fired in a Gridivew.  You cannot simply add a LinkButton called "Delete" and provide an event hander like this:

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="lnkRemoveEntry" runat="server" 
    OnClick="lnkRemoveEntry_Click" 
    Text="Delete" />
```

and expect to fire a GridView `RowDeleting` event.  You need to provide a CommandName in the Button.  For a Delete operation you need to add `CommandName="Delete"` to the Link Button.  [**See this for more on handling GridView operations**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.rowcommand%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

A GridView recognizes several other CommandName values as well: "Insert", "Edit", "Update", "Cancel". Each fires it's own appropriate Gridview row specific events and the ALL fire the RowCommand event.

When you don't specify a DataSource you have to manually wire up all the editing command events, this includes making sure you grab the correct PK's to handle Delete and Update operations.

Comment: I know this already; I implemented this in plenty of places.  I was quoting others that I tested that one as well but that didn't work.  I was not expecting LinkButton to fire RowDeleting.